# How to configure webpack + babel for ie11?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Babel configs:

```
"babel": {
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "ie": "9"
      },
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 3
    }
  ]
]},
```

Node Modules:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.9",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9",
"babel-loader": "^8",
"core-js": "^3",
"regenerator": "^0.14"
"webpack": "^4.40",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3"},
```

Webpack configs

```
{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(dom7|ssr-window|swiper)\/).*/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
},
```

In Internet Explorer 11, I get an error "Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'"

Answer (score 4):

You've configured `webpack` and `@babel/preset-env` correctly here, but unfortunately, `core-js`, which `@babel/preset-env` relies on for all of it's polyfills doesn't polyfill any Browser APIs, which `Element.closest()` is. It only polyfills JavaScript.

The difference between Browser/Web APIs and JavaScript is very nuanced - it includes anything which you access from a Node/Element and any [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) listed here

If you would like to polyfill `Element.closest`, you'll have to include the polyfill separately - [`element-closest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-closest) seems popular!